# Script for organizing data with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Hello I am trying to create a script that will take data from one google sheet and format it into another based on multiple conditions. Essentially a poor mans labor assignor based on when employees clock in and their work preference. however they will only be assigned if they are clocked in. and they will be assigned based on the order they clock in. They will then be sorted into groups based on preference. However if their preference is for a job that is already full then they will have to be assigned to a different task.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSlkg.png)I have the simple break down on a google sheet of the outline of what I want but I am not even sure if this is even possible on google sheets. The first photo is the data of people and the variables that the system will use to "assign/sort" them. The second is the limits of the size of the groups they can sort them into. 3rd is the inputs that can be changed that tell how many groups are allowed of each. 4th is the final page where all people will be sorted into the groups based on all the conditions.

Basically the system will sort people based on their preference and in order of their priority. If someone has highest priority and they have a preference of k then they will get k as long as there are open spots available.

I understand that this can be confusing but Im trying to see if this can be done with a script in google sheets.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please show a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results, instead of screenshots.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get the "K" group, use `query()`, like this:

```
=query(A2:D, "select A where B = 'Yes' order by C desc, D asc limit 6", 0)
```

This will assign the first six clocked in people whose preference is "K" to that group in priority order. If there are not that many people whose preference is "K", clocked in people whose preference is "A" are filled in, again in priority order.

With that done, your problem description calls for another 16 people to be assigned to the "A" group regardless of what their preference is, solely based on their priority while making sure that someone already assigned to the "K" group is not included in the "A" group as well.

Assuming the results of the "K" group formula above are in `K2:K7`, you can get the "A" group like this:

```
=array_constrain( 
  filter( 
    sort(A2:D, D2:D, true), 
    "Yes" = sort(B2:B, D2:D, true), 
    isna(match(sort(A2:A, D2:D, true), K2:K7, 0)) 
  ), 
  16, 1 
)
```